# Accessing remote windows system from MAC

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, remote-access

I want to access a remote windows system from my Mac system and work on that(coding in visual studio). Is it possible to remotely access a windows system from Mac? I am sure it should be possible but not sure how. Can anyone please guide me?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac Remote Desktop:

http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client